I am getting a logging in using static token error and I don't know how to fix it
I'm in the process of creating a Discord bot, I can't seem to get it working. Whenever I run main.py it returns with the error message [2024-07-02 17:20:46] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token. My bot token seems up to date in my .env file and it matches with the discord bot token in the Developer portal. This is the code I have in main.py
from typing import Final
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Intents, Client, Message
from responses import get_response

load_dotenv()
TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents: Intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client: Client = Client(intents=intents)

async def send_message(message: Message, user_message: str) -> None:
    if not user_message:
        print('Message empty because intents were not enabled probably.')
        return

    is_private = user_message[0] == '?'
    if is_private:
        user_message = user_message[1:]

    try:
        response: str = get_response(user_message)
        if is_private:
            await message.author.send(response)
        else:
            await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error sending message: {e}')

@client.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    username: str = str(message.author)
    user_message: str = message.content
    channel: str = str(message.channel)

    print(f'[{channel}] {username}: "{user_message}"')
    await send_message(message, user_message)

def main() -> None:
    client.run(TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

None of the posts I have found helped me on this, and I was expecting an easier time with this and having it work. I followed a tutorial as I am relatively new in this topic.
Here is my error message in full:
[2024-07-02 17:25:00] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1025, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1126, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1159, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 575, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 557, in _do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 917, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/main.py", line 49, in main
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 858, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 786, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 620, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 816, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 638, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1197, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 581, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 944, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1257, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1226, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/siddharthn/Python/DiscordBot/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1027, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')]


This question is similar to: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108) Discord/python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
